# How to fire onlick() function only when a radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am practising my JS and I am making a battleship game. I have a grid of buttons 10x10. Each button has `reply_click()` function that gives me `id` corresponding to the relevant position on the grid.

```html
<button id="00" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></button>
```

and

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
   //some code 
}
```

I want to fire `reply_click()` function only when a radio button is checked and ignore it in all other scenarios.

I tried to a make a radio button with `onclick()` function that checks if that radio button is checked, but I was not able to place `reply_click()` function inside it.

*Example:*

```html
<input type="radio" id="1s" name="ship" onclick="check()">
<label for="1s">1 square ship</label><br>
```

and

```js
function check() {
   if (document.getElementById('1s').checked) {
       //dont know what to put here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this solution.  Not really sure what you are asking but this seems like it might help.

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id) 
    {
       console.log(clicked_id);
       if(clicked_id !== "00")console.log('do stuff');
    }


function check(event)
{
    
    if(document.getElementById(event.id).checked)
        {
           reply_click(event.id);
        }
}
```

```html
<button id="00" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></button>


<input type="radio" id="1s" name="ship" onclick="check(this)">
<label for="1s">1 square ship</label><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add if statement inside reply_click.. eg:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
    if (document.getElementById('1s').checked) {
        //  Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `disable` the button and only `enable` when a `radio` button is **checked**

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
  console.log("Definaley i am not disabled now: "+clicked_id); 
}


function check()
{
    if(document.getElementById('1s').checked)
        {
          
           document.getElementById("00").disabled = false;
           document.getElementById("00").innerText = "Now i am enable";
        }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="1s" name="ship" onclick="check()">
<label for="1s">1 square ship</label><br>

<button id="00"  onclick="reply_click(this.id)" disabled>I am disabled</button>
```